# Filter for images with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have categories [`sports`,`naturel`,`animals`] and if I click sports than  `data-id="sports"` img must appear and another data-id must be invisible how can I do that ?
[in stackoverflow is my codes not appear correctly please click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/XMJxBb)

and my function for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".filter li").on("click",function(){
      var activeId = $(this).attr("id");

  });
});
```

this is basic how can I improve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // if you want to initially hide all the images then uncomment the following line
  //$("img[data-id]").hide(); 

  $(".filter li").on("click",function(){
      var activeId = $(this).attr("id");

      $("img[data-id]").hide();                      // hide all images that have the attribute data-id
      $("img[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").show(); // show the one with the data-id attribute equal to activeId
  });
});
```

Comment: example is very well and explanatory but why didn't work I don't understand

Comment: @recruit_man you seem to be already using a slideshow library that handles the switching of images. Try and turn it of!

Comment: @recruit_man With the plugin on, the functionality you want is already there (if you click an li the according image show up and the rest is hidden).

Comment: @recruit_man I didn't understand your last comment, would you explain please!

Comment: sorry about my english..I see what are you talking about but is there any example for this function..andy I'm talking about categories which is the top of the carousel

Comment: @recruit_man Ah! I understood now! You want when you click on the sports button to leave only images of sports in the slideshow, and when pressing animals to keep only animals and so on. I think you'll have to create three slideshows and hide or show the slideshow you want!

Comment: hide or show reasonable because it will be dynamic and categories can Increase

Comment: The plugin is already using hide/show for the images, if you hide or show an image, the plugin will hide or show the images it want so it will override your decision, the only way is to make multiple slideshows!

Comment: but multiple slideshows aren't reasonable..for example I have 10 categories or more than 10 than what will we do ? :))

Comment: You can implement your own slideshow (it will take you sometime).

Comment: thanks for your helps and relevance and sorry for my bad english and bad js:)

Comment: @recruit_man I'm sorry as well that you didn't get what you want! I'm going to delete this answer in a moment as it didn't really help solving your problem!